# Pycharm runs unittests in directory where files are located

Tags: pycharm

I like to keep my unittests in several files all in a subdirectory under the project root, a pretty common pattern.

However when I run these unittests in PyCharm, the current working directory is that tests subdirectory.  I'd like to have that current working directory be the project root, to ensure configuration files are found.

The only place in settings I see that references working directory is the console, which doesn't help the above behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you want is specific to each target. That is why it is not in the "general settings". Instead, in the menu where you can select the target to run there s is an "Edit configurations..." option. There you can select the configuration of your "tests" target. Then you can set the "Working directory" of that target to be the project root like the image below.

[image]